# Different GADBannerView in TableView

Tags: ios, admob, tableview

I want to have a `UITableView` which contains an Admob Banner every 13th cell.
This does already work, but my problem is that I want to show different banners (4 at the moment). So that at cell 13 we have banner 1 and at cell 26 banner 2 and so on.

My problem is, that I don't know how to realize that. Currently I receive the first banner in every cell - which - I guess - means that the code just loads 1 banner in every cell and then says "Yep. I have my ad. Now I'm happy" and then not loads the 2 banner in the 26 cell.

I did subclass my "AdCell" and have a Bool which says "hasAD" to prevent that every cell reloads when scrolling (but maybe that is part of my problem?). Maybe you can help me.

The Cell in the Table:

```
   AdCell *cell = (AdCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AdCell"];
    cell.tag = 4;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AdCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"AdCell"];

    }

    if (![cell hasAD]){

        // Create a view of the standard size at the bottom of the screen.
        // Available AdSize constants are explained in GADAdSize.h.
        GADAdSize customAdSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(290, 120));

        DFPBannerView *bannerView_ = [[DFPBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:customAdSize];

        //The AdCounter is what i said with banner1,banner2 
        if (adCounter == 4){
            adCounter = 1;
        }
        bannerView_.adUnitID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LEFTOUT-%i/banner",adCounter];

        // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
        // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
        bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

        //Center AD
        [bannerView_ setCenter:CGPointMake(cell.center.x, cell.center.y)];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:bannerView_];
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
        [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];


        adCounter++;

        [cell setHasAD];
    }



    return cell;
```

Comment: what is the difference between DFPBannerView and GADBannerView?

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, check the `indexPath.row` value. If it's divisible by 13, then load an ad cell.

You could then extend that technique to check which ad to load - so if it's row 26, 26 % 13 = 2, so load ad #2 and so on.

Putting logic in the cell subclass violates the model-view-controller pattern - your cells are dumb recipients of data and it's the `UITableViewController` class that decides what they should display.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried the divisible idea, but the problem is that when the indexPath.row gets higher (there are more than 200 cells) there are more numbers which are divisible by for example 26. So that unfortunately doesn't work